# How do I save an automated XML file with a save dialog?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to save an XML file that was generated automatically with XMLWriter, however I want the user to be able to save the document to their location and name of choice via a save dialog, only problem I face is that save dialog is not a property of System.XML, could I get some help?

Comment: [How to: Save Files Using the SaveFileDialog Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-save-files-using-the-savefiledialog-component)

Comment: You can drag an drop a SaveFileDialog from the Tool Box to your form. It will appear in the component tray. Set Properties in the properties window then use in code. This will provide a file location but it does not actually save the file. You need to provide the code to save it.